# Trouble outputting a recordset value with fieldname a reserved word in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, jet

In vba, I've created a recordset called 'rs' that includes a field named "EmployeeName" and another named "Position". If I execute

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact").Cells(row, 1) = rs("EmployeeName")
```

it works fine, but if I instead do

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contact").Cells(row, 2) = rs("Position")
```

I get an error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." Run-Time error 3265

I'm pretty sure this is because "Position" is a reserved word, but I don't know a work-around.

Comment: try `rs("[Position]")`

Comment: I thought that would work too, but it didn't.

Comment: Can you reference the field by index? ie something like rs[1]?

Comment: Yes, but I just figured out the solution.  I needed to do rs("Employees.Position").  "Employees" is the name of my table.

Answer (score 0):

rs("Employees.Position"), where Employees is the name of my table, did the trick.

Comment: Is your Recordset based on a query that references more than one table?

Comment: No, it's just based on one table.